# Why ndk's `stlport` link error when I don't insert some codes?

Tags: android-ndk

I encounters some weird situations about ndk's `stlport` linking.
My snippet codes as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "igslib_imodule_manager.h"
#include "serial_manager_sample.h"
#include "rtc_sample.h"

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    igslib::IModuleManager* mm = GetModuleManagerInstance();
    int rtn = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    //igslib::serial_manager_sample::UartSend(mm);
    //igslib::serial_manager_sample::UartReceive(mm);
    //igslib::rtc_sample::GetTime(mm);
    return rtn;
}
```

That will result in `stlport` linking errors as follows:

```
naivechou@~/project/igslib/google_code/build/components_sample/jni>ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/c/project/igslib/google_code/build/components_sample/jni/Android.mk:components_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -ligslib_module_manager
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: components_sample <= main.cpp
[armeabi] Executable     : components_sample
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf():C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_streambuf.c:41: error: undefined reference to 'std::locale::~locale()'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios():C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_ios.h:59: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::~ios_base()'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::__node_alloc::allocate(unsigned int&):C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:158: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_allocate(unsigned int&)'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::__node_alloc::deallocate(void*, unsigned int):C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:161: error: undefined reference to 'std::__node_alloc::_M_deallocate(void*, unsigned int)'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function igslib::CModuleManager::GetInstance():C:/project/igslib/google_code/build/module_manager/jni/../../../src/module_manager/igslib_module_manager.cpp:19: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZN6igslib14CModuleManager11GetInstanceEv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf():C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_sstream.c:59: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED2Ev+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::pair<std::string const, igslib::CModuleManager::SModuleInfo>::~pair():C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_string_base.h:156: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o):(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt4pairIKSsN6igslib14CModuleManager11SModuleInfoEED2Ev+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ../../../out/libigslib_module_manager.a(igslib_module_manager.o): in function std::vector<igslib::CModuleManager::SModuleInfo, std::allocator<igslib::CModuleManager::SModuleInfo> >::~vector():C:/bin/android-ndk-r10c/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:323: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
...(After the text ellipsis)...
```

But if I **uncomment** the first line `igslib::serial_manager_sample::UartSend(mm);`, everything's fine:

```
naivechou@~/project/igslib/google_code/build/components_sample/jni>ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/c/project/igslib/google_code/build/components_sample/jni/Android.mk:components_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -ligslib_module_manager
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: components_sample <= main.cpp
[armeabi] Executable     : components_sample
[armeabi] Install        : components_sample => libs/armeabi/components_sample
[custom install path]: ../../../out
```

I just can't figure out what happens? Why I **DON'T** insert codes will raise errors?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to tell without seeing your Application.mk and Android.mk, but it looks like you are using LOCAL_LDLIBS to list the igslib_module_manager library as a dependency to your executable.

This is not a good idea because ndk-build doesn't know about this library's own dependencies when you do this, and the final link command will not be correct (the way Unix linking works is pretty sophisticated, but explains the behaviour you're seeing). That's why ndk-build complains with a WARNING by the way.

You should instead define a module for igslib_module_manager, even if the library is prebuilt, then use LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += igslib_module_manager to your Android.mk instead.

As a side note, the reason why uncommenting the line 'solves' the issue is because this introduces an additional dependency in the generated object file for 'main.cpp' that ends up pulling just the right amount of STLport into the final link command. But that's really just by chance, you should really list your dependencies properly to ensure everything works properly everytime.

Comment: Thank's for response, I'll try prebuilt library mechanism again. :)